# Import single file to OSB

Tags: soa, osb, oracle-service-bus

We keep all our osb projects in source control. I want to write a script to extract the project files from source control and import them into an OSB environment.

All the tutorials online show how to make an export from one OSB and import that into another. I need to know if I have a single file (e.g. test.xsd) how can I import it into OSB via a command or script. 
(I know how to do this with lots of manual steps involving eclipse but it must be possible via the command line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version are you using? Check this out 
[Offline Oracle Service Bus Scripting](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2013/04/offline-oracle-service-bus.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven,you can export the OSB projects as jar to include only the required files( e.g test.xsd) and import the jar in the osb environment .